# Convert date from ajax post in controller to yyyyMMdd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, date

I am getting some dates in string in an ajax post to the controller.

Code

```
public ActionResult ModifyPartnerForOrganization(Guid partnerID, string aliasName, string effectiveDate, string expirationDate)
        {
            Partner partner = new Partner();
            partner.PartnerId = partnerID;
            partner.ExternalId = aliasName;
            partner.EffectiveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(effectiveDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
            partner.ExpirationDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expirationDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
}
```

The date coming from client side are in `MM-DD-YYYY` format for example  `01/10/2014(just for explanning adding the 01/oct/2014) to controller as`10/1/2014.

When trying to parse get this error.`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Any help on this??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So okay, the format received from the client is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Then you should parse it like that, not like `yyyyMMdd`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(effectiveDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Also note the use of `MM` instead of `mm`, since `mm` is minutes, not months.

---

All the formats you specified so far:

```
string effectiveDate = "01/10/2014";
string effectiveDate2 = "30/oct/2014";
string effectiveDate3 = "1/10/2014";

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(effectiveDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(effectiveDate2, "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
DateTime d3 = DateTime.ParseExact(effectiveDate3, "d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: after using the above code , i am facing this problem i passed this  date from client side 30-oct-2014 which is converted to 30-jan -2014 so that is wrong . What i am expecting is 30-oct-2014 to be converted to 2014-10-30.

Comment: i have written for easy understanding this is another example 1/1/2016(jan/01/2014 this is the date i have selected in the calendar.just for understanding i am adding this).1/1/2016 is what i am getting in controller .

Comment: it is failing to parse same error for 1/1/2016(jan/01/2014 this is the date i have selected in the calendar.just for understanding i am adding this).1/1/2016 is what i am getting in controller

Comment: But that still not the format you specified. You said `dd`, not `d`. `ParseExact` is very exact, as in the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62803/discussion-between-ankur-and-patrick-hofman).

Comment: @ankur: See the updated answer to include all the formats you specified so far.